# Fetch paginated data without knowing the page number

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loops, pagination

I have an API that only allows fetching 1000 rows/fetch.

So for instance, if I want to retrieve all the data from the API, the idea is to loop through the response data each time fetching and check the `length` of it (if responseData.length !== 0, then continue fetching, stop when responseData.length === 0, also increase the `firstRow` every time it starts the new loop until it reaches to the end (responseData.length === 0)

```
const fetchDataByRowCount = async (url, token, rowCount = 2, firstRow = 0) => {
// firstRow is the value where the next fetch starts (E.g: 0-999, 1000-1999, etc.).
// rowCount is the value for total rows fetched (E.g: 1000 rows for each fetching time).
  const data = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: `${url}?rowCount=${rowCount}&firstRow=${firstRow}`,
    headers: {
      client_id: "",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
  return data.data;
};
```

```
export const paginatedFetch = async (url, type, rowCount = 2, firstRow = 0) => {
  let newResponse;
  let total = [];
  let token = await getToken(type); // stored to reuse token within an hour
  do {
    if (!token) {
      const newToken = await getToken(type);
      newResponse = await fetchDataByRowCount(url, newToken);
    } else {
      newResponse = await fetchDataByRowCount(
        url,
        token,
        (rowCount = 2),
        (firstRow = 0)
      );
    }
    // console.log(total, "total");
    total = [...total, ...newResponse];
    // newResponse = [];
    let newFirstRow = firstRow + 1000;

    newResponse = await fetchDataByRowCount(
      url,
      token,
      (rowCount = 2),
      newFirstRow
    );
    total = [...total, ...newResponse];
  } while (newResponse.length !== 0);
  return total;
};
```

But the problem is that my function didn't exit the `do while` loop, the `newResponse` always returns value !==0.
Also, the function only runs once.

Could you guys help me check this, please?

Comment: I think you wanted to call `paginatedFetch` instead of `await fetchDataByRowCount(url, token, rowCount = 2, newFirstRow)` near the end of your code, but still, I wouldn't trust calling a recursive function that has a loop.

Comment: Yeh. I thought so too. But haven't found a way to tackle the problem yet.

Comment: It would greatly help if we knew what was the prototype of `fetchDataByRowCount` (what are the parameters, what purpose do they serve, why some are optional, what does it returns, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted, there's still a thing I can't figure out, and it's `rowCount`, so I let it as it is in the following "remastered" code:

```
export const paginatedFetch = async (url, type, rowCount = 2, firstRow = 0) => {
  let newResponse;
  let total = [];
  let token;
  let numberOfRows = firstRow;
  do {
    if (!token) token = await getToken(type);

    newResponse = await fetchDataByRowCount(
      url,
      token,
      (rowCount = 2),
      numberOfRows
    );
    total = [...total, ...newResponse];
    numberOfRows += 1000;
  } while (newResponse.length !== 0);
  return total;
};
```

I got rid of a few things that were redundant, and made the code a tiny bit more efficient with variable assignments etc.

You also mention this:

> the newResponse always returns value !==0.

Be careful doing this, as `newResponse` is initially `undefined`. Now I never used `do...while` loops so I don't know *exactly* what could happen, but it could for example not run at all. Hence the `Also, the function only runs once` if you're speaking about the `paginatedFetch` function.

Now if I were to re-write it, I would do it like so:

```
export const paginatedFetch = async (url, type, rowCount = 2, firstRow = 0) => {
  let total = [];
  let token;
  let numberOfRows = firstRow;
  while (true) {
    if (!token) token = await getToken(type);
    let res = await fetchDataByRowCount(
      url,
      token,
      (rowCount = 2),
      numberOfRows
    );
    total = [...total, ...res];
    numberOfRows += 1000;
    if (res.length <= 0) break;
  }
  return total;
};
```

Again, be careful with `while (true)`, you have to be absolutely **sure** of what the API returns and res is indeed an `array`.

The better solution would be the API (if you are the developer) giving an endpoint to count the total number of rows. That way, you would have a way to be absolutely sure how many rows there are and write your code around that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!

So ```rowCount``` is the value for total rows fetched each time (E.g: 1000 rows for each fetching time). I edited the question.